# How can I get the total number of certain text in my `GridView` and display in a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display the total number of certain text in a column in a label in my web app
So in my `GridView` I have a column that contains two text.  one is E1 and the other is E3.  Now what I would like to do is have two labels displaying the total count of E1 and the second label displaying the total count of E3.

So if this is my Column:

```
| Type  |
| E1    |
| E3    |
| E3    |
| E1    |
| E1    |
```

Something similar to this

```
Total E1 = 3
Total E3 = 2
```

I have no idea on how to achieve this so hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Just count the Cells whos value is your desired data, e.g. a string:

```
        int iCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView.RowCount-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < GridView.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                if (GridView[j, i].Value.ToString() == "E1")
                    iCount++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks,
I am getting an error at this code `if (GridView[j, i].Value.ToString() == "E1")
                        iCount++;
                    lblE3.Text = iCount.ToString();`  Error:  `'GridView' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: you'll have to change "GridView" with the name of the gridview you used in your code.

Comment: I have, but the error is `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'GridView'`
So my code is then: `int iCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridViewOffice365.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < GridViewOffice365.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (GridViewOffice365[j, i].Value.ToString() == "E1")
                        iCount++;
                    lblE3.Text = iCount.ToString();
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int CountItem1 = 0;
int CountItem2 = 0;
int ColumnNumber = 2; //This is the column you want to verify. Starts from 0 to GridViewOffice365.ColumnNumbers -1 
for each (GridViewRow row in GridViewOffice365.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[ColumnNumber].Text == "E1")
    {
       CountItem1++;
    }
    else if (row.Cells[ColumnNumber].Text == "E3")
    {
       CountItem2++;
    }
}
lblE1.Text = "Total E1: " CountItem1.ToString();
lblE3.Text = "Total E3: " + CountItem2.ToString();
```